# increasing te size of an array

Tags: java, arrays

i have this to complete :

```
 public class TabCouples {

private Couple[] tab;
private final int size = 10;


public TabCouples()
{
  //some code 1
}

public void add(Couple C)
{
    //some code 2
}
```

where Couple is a class with constructor Couple(int a, int b). The add method should increase the size of my array by size before adding C to it.
So i was thinking of creating a new array and then copying the elements to the new array before increasing its size. How can i implement this given the above skeleton

Comment: Is this your homework ? You are trying to implement an `ArrayList`, don't do it unless it is explicitely your assignment.

Comment: yeah it's kinda a homework...i just need a tip how to do it

Comment: if you change your array length why are you using a mutable array Couple[]?

Comment: Couple is another class already created

Comment: @lukasirides : You have the answer in your question.

Comment: if in code 1 i put >tab = new Couple[size]; i won't be able to increase it's size again.
@Dici : can u explain ?

Comment: You said `creating a new array and then copying the elements to the new array`. That's exactly what you need to do. Just a tip, a classic growth for an `ArrayList` is to double the size each time the list muste be resized.

Comment: yea but sincein my constructor i'll be doing  tab = new Couple[size]; so in my code 2 i'll create a new array....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the size of an Array but you can create a new one and copy the old array on it.

So on your method:

```
public void add (Couple c){
  Couple[] newTab = Arrays.copyOf(tab, tab.length +size);
  tab= newTab;
  // add the new element on the new array tab

}
```

**Note:** You should use ArrayList as we suggested you even in the other question, unless you have a very good reason to do this :). **So stop asking the same question please!**

Comment: one last question : won't tab = newTab give an indexoutofbound exception because in my constructor i'll be doing  tab = new Couple[size]; ?

Comment: No. After tab=newTab the variable tab will point to an array of length (size + old tab). It will give you a NullPointerException if you don't instantiate tab at the beginning, before calling add(Couple c)! This is because you need the old tab length (tab.length) in order to create the newTab array.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use `ArrayList`.
2. Implement it yourself by creating a new array and copying the old array over to it. This also requires keeping track of how many elements in the current array that you are currently using. Basically you will be rewriting `ArrayList`. This is a good learning exercise, but if your assignment has other goals, it will probably take more time than needed.